# Odata Metadata format missing from Web API 2 response

Tags: c#, odata, asp.net-web-api2

I have a web api 2 project and want to expose the models as an Odata service so that it is queryable.

This is the setup I have done:
In `WebApiConfig.Register()` I have

```
config.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

The following code is in the Values Controller

```
// GET api/values
[EnableQuery (PageSize=1)]
public IQueryable<TestProduct> Get()
{
    var str = new List<TestProduct>
    {
        new TestProduct {Name = "Dark", Value = "Lord"},
        new TestProduct {Name = "Dark", Value = "Elf"}
    };
    var hello = str.AsQueryable();
    return hello;
}
```

When I query

```
http://localhost:51823/api/values?$filter=Name eq 'Elf'
```

The result I get is:

```
[
    {
        "Name": "Dark",
        "Value": "Elf"
    }
]
```

I am missing the `$odata.metadata` properties and the `inlinecount` property. How can I add that to the response.
Ideally i would be looking for:

```
    [
 "odata.metadata":"http://localhost:43111/api/$metadata#TestProducts",
            "odata.count":"1",
"value":
        {
            "Name": "Dark",
            "Value": "Elf"
        }
    ]
```

I don't plan on using EF.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
http://localhost:51823/api/values?$filter=Name eq 'Elf'&$inlinecount=allpages
```

To get metadata info add the odata=fullmetadata to the Accept header eg:

```
Accept:application/json;odata=fullmetadata
```